# How do i ignore if that particular socket is already connected?

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets

below method will connect to socket port of port number 11 and 14. so initially when i connect both ports 11 and 14 they get connected and the app runs, if in between a port gets disconnected ex port 14. and only port 11 is connected now.if i try to load port. both port will be initialized, the problem what i have is sometimes disconnected port 14 gets connected but sometimes connected port 11 gets disconnected and port 14 gets connected. 
how do sense if port 11 is connected then dont bother initialize and if port 14 is disconnected let it connect again.

is there any  builting in feature like `port.connected` in c#

```
try
   {

                            Thread.Sleep(100);
                            TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any,ports);

                            clientSocket = default(TcpClient);

                            int counter = 0;

                            serverSocket.Start();

                            counter += 1;

                            dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>

                            {

                                clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

                            }));

                            MessageBox.Show(ports + " " + "Connected!");


                        } 

         catch (Exception w) 
                        { 
                            MessageBox.Show(ports + " " + "Connection error!"); 
                        }
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: done! @Frank please check now